# Twitter API OAuth PHP post_tweet.php

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

I'm unable to get any results following to post a tweet from php. I've registered my app with twitter and got my credentials. I've made a page called access_tokens.php, and downloaded an OAuth library called tmhOAuth.php. I'm following an example tutorial exactly, and nothing seems to be appearing - is there any help that can be offered?

access_tokens.php

```
<?php

$consumer_key = 'xx';
$consumer_secret = 'xx';
$user_token = 'xx';
$user_secret = 'xx';

//xx is the replacement for my actual values

?>
```

post_tweet.php

```
<?php
//Load the app's keys into memory
require 'app_tokens.php';

//Load the tmOAuth library
require 'tmhOAuth.php';

//Create an OAuth connection to the Twitter API
$connection = new tmhOAut(array(
                            'consumer_key'   =>     $consumer_key,
                            'consumer_secret'=>     $consumer_secret,
                            'user_token'     =>     $user_token,
                            'user_secret'    =>     $user_secret
                            ));

//Send a tweet
$code = $connection -> request('POST',
    $connection -> url('1.1/statuses/update'),
    array('status' => 'Hello Twitter'));

//A response code of 200 is a success
if ($code == 200){
    print "Tweet sent";
}
else{
    print "Error:$code";
}                               

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find if that OAuth library has support yet, because I tried to do the same thing some months ago and I found some posts telling that since march it couldn't be used no more. Anyway, I'm not sure if it was that library, but if you code twitter related you have to be aware that they change their API often.

Comment: IDK if that OAuth library was supported, but I did get it to work with another one. Now if only I could get the timeline to display instead of being blank. Yay for coding!